# Store data that would be sent over the socket when it disconnects and manage it when socket reconnects

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, python-multithreading

I have a problem where I need to store data on a disk when the TCP socket disconnects for whatever reason that would otherwise be sent over that socket and simultaneously check when a new connection is established and I can't find a solution to this.
What I have is:

```py
def start_server_for_clients(srv, port):
    client = None

    try:
        srv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        srv.bind(('', port))
        srv.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        srv.listen(5)

        print('Waiting for clients on port %s' % port)

        while True:
            client, address = srv.accept()
            client.settimeout(10)
            
            print('Connected client %s %s.' % (address[0], address[1]))
            t = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client, address))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        if client:
            client.close()
```

`handle_client` is a function where data is processed and sent over the socket every second in a `while` loop. I need that processed data either way: connected or not and store it.

Now my logic to separate data processing and socket communication into different parts but where does it fit into threading once the connection is back up again because I would need to clear off the stored data first while simultaneously storing/buffering newly accumulated data and only then proceed to instant communication between sockets? Do I need to use `select` in this thread and spawn another one to for storing and recovering?

Comment: Your question is kinda incoherent. I don't understand why storing data would have anything to do with threads.

Comment: I think that I can't yet wrap my head around this logic. That's not a threading problem. My main concern is detecting when the connection is dropped so I could proceed with storing data and then when it's up again to proceed with cleaning up and going back to normal communication.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Drop a connection and see what happens. Then make your program detect that.

Comment: I'm doing that at the moment. The trend I see is that I've probably overcomplicated this whole thing but I also probably just needed to ask this to narrow down the problem. Sorry if I was inconvenient.